Can I make TCP_NODELAY a default setting for all connections on a GNU/Linux system?
This article:
It’s always TCP_NODELAY. Every damn time.
suggests, as a bottom line, to set TCP_NODELAY by default, always. Can I do that on a (recent) GNU/Linux system...

As root, for all sockets opened by all users?
As a user, for all sockets for processes I create (or child processes of a given process etc.)?

In this question I learned this was not possible on Solaris in 2011.

Setting TCP_NODELAY as a system wide default would  break the expectations existing application have at the current socket API and thus might impact applications, especially the performance. I don't think that this is a good idea.

@SteffenUllrich: Perhaps; but just suppose I want to do it as an experiment.

Then you probably have to change and recompile your kernel for this. There is no such global option.

@SteffenUllrich A system-wide LD_PRELOAD of a shared library that intercepts socket() calls and sets TCP_NODELAY on TCP sockets might work.  I wouldn't try that on any system I don't have direct physical access to the console, though.  And even then I'd have a rescue disk handy.

@AndrewHenle: That dangerous?

@einpoklum I don't know as I've never done it.  But it's mucking around with all networks along with all processes.  There's quite the potential for breaking things in ways not fixable remotely.  If you try it, make sure you account for both 32- and 64-bit processes.  If you set LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mylib.so, that will be applied to both 32- and 64-bit processes.  That would need to be addressed - IIRC if you have a $LIB in the envval it will expand to /lib or /lib64 as appropriate.

@AndrewHenle: So, I'm supposed to use a dollar sign in the value of LD_PRELOAD, which expands according to the bit with? Can you perhaps link to another SO question about this.

@einpoklum I found this, which seems to be consistent with what I remember: Using LD_PRELOAD mixed 64bit/32bit environment in Linux
